# How to process using nested processes

Tags: python, multiprocess

The code below:

```
import time, multiprocessing, os

def foo():
    logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
    logger.warning(os.getpid())
    time.sleep(30)

class Object(object):
    def run(self):
        for i in range(5):
            proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo)
            proc.start()

for i in range(2):
    obj = Object()
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=obj.run)
    proc.start()
```

starts 10 nested `multiprocessing.Processes`:

[image]

Is is safe to run the `Processes` used in a code above, nested?

[image]

Comment: You can run as many nested threads as you want, this doesn't impact whether they are safe or not. The data and how they use it determines whether threading is safe or a deadlock/livelock/race will occur.

Comment: it is safe as long as you have enough cpu/memory/fds.